# App Engine not caching static CSS files

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm just getting started with my first app engine site. I followed the hello world sample to get my home page up and running. I added a css file and declared a static handler for it in my `app.yaml`. Here is the full content:

```
application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /css/.*/(.*)
  mime_type: text/css
  static_files: css/\1
  upload: css/(.*)
  expiration: "30d"

- url: /.*
  script: myapp.app
```

When I use the Audit feature of the Chrome developer tools, it warns that my CSS file is explicitly non-cacheable. I tried increasing the expiration time, but that didn't help.

Is there anything else I need to do to enable caching for static files? I haven't messed around with any settings in the site dashboard, so it should be using the default settings.

Comment: Caching is only available for billing-enabled apps.

Comment: @pdknsk - can you provide a reference that supports your statement

Comment: Are you doing this on a deployed app or SDK?

Comment: I was performing the audit against the SDK. The deployed app is caching properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run this same test on the SDK against localhost, I get the same warning that none of my CSS is cached and that it's set to be explicitly non-cachable.

When I deploy the app and run the test from .appspot.com, I only get a warning for the jquery CDN link, and all of my CSS files are cached.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Looks like the files are marked as proxy-cacheable, but I'm still seeing them as non-browser cacheable.

Comment: Thank you for confirming this. I was auditing the SDK on localhost. The deployed app caches properly.